# Does Boltzmann distribution refers to microstates or particle's probability?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am reading about the Boltzmann distribution and I can't grasp the following:

$$p_i = e^{-\frac{E_i}{k_B T}}$$

Is this the probability finding the system at a microstate with Energy $E_i$ or the probability finding a particle with energy $E_i$ (useful for transitions in spectroscopy etc).

This distribution is for canonical ensemble where system has constant $(T, V, N)$ (coupled to a heat bath). The probabilities for the microstates of the isolated system (system+heat bath) are equal whereas the probability for finding system A in a particular microstate in general will not (in accordance with the formula). So if we map the different microstates in distributions (i.e. the set of all microstates of system with a specific energy) the formula is interpreted as the fraction of microstates of A with the specific energy.

For example we can have $3$ distributions $D_1, D_2, D_3$ with energies $E_1, E_2, E_3$ respectively and each containing $Ω_1, Ω_2, Ω_3$ microstates. The probability therefore $p_i$ therefore, is simply the ratio:

$$\frac{Ω_i}{Ω_{system}}$$

This is how I understand it (maybe wrong). What I don't get is the connection between probabilities of microstates and the probabilities for particles (if any).